# How to get an equation system from a Simplex table

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

Let's assume I already have a simplex table (with an optimal solution):
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc|c} 
& x_1 & x_2 & S_1 & S_2 & \\
S_1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
S_2 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & 0  & 4 \\
\hline
P & 5 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 1  & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

**note**: the above table is not a real problem.

How do I get the original problem model from this?

Comment: An answer [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-find-the-original-linear-program-using-Table-of-Simplex)

Comment: @Kuifje thanks, i was able to follow the solution but not entirely, i'm still trying to understand, i'm terrible with matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write a better and correct example, you can find it easier. Just make sure that:

1) The matrix in front of your basic variables should be the identity matrix.

2) The objective function row in the optimal tableau will have 0s for basic variables.

I'll change your example to the following and show you the steps to retrieve your original problem from the optimal tableau.

The original problem (which we want to get at the end):

```
Maximize    Z = 3x + 2y

subject to: 

2x + y ≤ 18
2x + 3y ≤ 42
3x + y ≤ 24
x ≥ 0 , y ≥ 0
```

Optimal Tableau:
\begin{array}{cccccc|c} 
& x & y & S_1 & S_2 & S_3 & \\
y & 0 & 1 & \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 12 \\
S_3 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-7}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 1  & 3\\
x & 1 & 0 & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{-1}{4} & 0  & 3 \\
\hline
Z & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 33
\end{array}

Your original tableau will have a form like this:
\begin{array}{rr|l}
* & * & 0 \\ \hline
N & I & b
\end{array}

and your optimal tableau will be:
\begin{array}{rr|l}
* & * & * \\ \hline
B^{-1} N & B^{-1} & B^{-1} b
\end{array}

So, under our slack variables (here $S_1, S_2, S_3$), we can find $ B^{-1} $ matrix:
\begin{array}{ccc} 
 \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &  \\
 \frac{-7}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 1  & \\
 \frac{3}{4} & \frac{-1}{4} & 0  &  \\
\end{array}

Now, the inverse of your $ B^{-1} $ matrix is your $B$ matrix. So, $B$ is:
\begin{array}{ccc} 
 1 & 0 & 2 &  \\
 3 & 0 & 2  & \\
 1 & 1 & 3  &  \\
\end{array}

Multiply $B$ by $[12, 3, 3]$ ($B^{-1} b$ in the optimal tableau) and you get the original $b$:
$[18, 42, 24]$
and multiply it by $B^{-1} N$ and you get your original $N$: 
\begin{array}{cc} 
 2 & 1 &  \\
 2 & 3 & \\
 3 & 1 &  \\
\end{array}

You can also refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1561037) answer for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: I was able to follow up with your steps, just one more question. According to the other post the `(B^-1)b` can be rearranged but honestly i couldn't understant the terms because in the optimal table they're always appear to be in the wrong order, but the `(B^-1)N` appear to be always the same in this case, and you just used them as they are. Also which `(B^-1)N` value did you use ?

Comment: Look at the original and optimal tableau representation that I showed above. Your original table is comprised of N (Non-basic) and I (your initial Basic). So, Your $B^{-1}N$ are those columns that were N in your original table. In your case, $B^{-1}N$ are those under columns $x, y$ in your optimal tableau.

Comment: I've figured it out, i had to multiply `(B^-1)N` with `B` to get the `original N`, since `(B^-1)N` now represents the `In`. The only thing i couldn't verify until now is the objective funcition `Z`, which terms were used to find it ? Sorry for the hard work, your notation is still different from what i'm using right now.

Comment: In the example I shared, $Z = 3x + 2y$. So, if in the optimal tableau $(y, S_3, x) = (12, 3, 3)$, then $Z = 3*3 + 2*12=33$